# mysql_real_escape_string not work in php 5.4.44

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, php-5.4

I am runing PHP Version 5.4.44 on my website  and try to us mysql_real_escape_string  but it does not give me any thing .`mysql_real_escape_strin`g   works just fine in localhost on my computer.Example Code

```
 <?php
    echo 'What is Your Name='.mysql_real_escape_string("my name is ");
    ?>
```

It output

> What is Your Name=

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for
>    use in an SQL statement

This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.

So you need to create a databsae connection before use of `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

   echo 'What is Your Name='.mysql_real_escape_string("my name is ");
```

**Output**

> What is Your Name=my name is

**Updated**

As per our discussion you are using mysqli so you are mixing mysql and mysqli in your code

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con,("my name is 'kk/'");//pass first parameter your database connection
```

Comment: Not Working @Saty                                                                                               include("define.php");
  $con=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else{
                    echo ' What is Your Name='.mysql_real_escape_string("my name is 'kk/'");
                }

Comment: mixing mysql and mysqli in your code. both are different. Either use mysql or mysqli

Comment: i am use mysqli for connect and try mysql_real_escape_string and mysqli_real_escape_string both not work @Saty

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,("my name is 'kk/'");` pass first parameter your $con variable

Comment: `echo 'What is Your Name='.mysql_real_escape_string("my name is ");`  - this line makes no sense.

Comment: its just a example use of my problem @zerkms

Comment: Have you pass first parameter as your database connection and checked

Comment: Have you tried with `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,("my name is 'kk/'");`

Comment: it work i am just forget to use $con in my mysqli_real_escape_string because mysql_real_escape_string works with out $con.thanks you Very much @Saty

Answer (score 0):

Is your database connection successful? Do you see any errors or warnings?

If its working fine on the localhost, check the connection string used to connect to the server.

Also, the function `mysql_real_escape_string` deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. You might want to look at [mysqli_real_escape_string.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)